# DML queries with different performance on similar servers

Tags: mysql, optimization, dml

I am measuring the performance between two servers that serve a database via MySQL 5.6. The DB1 server is a dedicated database server and the DB2 server shares resources with other services such as HTTP, Redis and AMQP (*it has more workload*).

The idea is separate all DB2 services on dedicated servers. The problem comes with the performance of DML commands between servers. Executing the same query, the DB2 (*shared server*) performs better than the dedicated server (*between 400ms and 3500ms faster on average in all queries*). They two servers mount the same type of hardware, operating system (*CentOS 6*) and the database is identical (*including indexes*).

DB1 has CPU with 8 threads and 32GB of RAM. The my.cnf configuration is as follows:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

# Fine Tuning
thread_stack = 512K
key_buffer = 1G
max_allowed_packet = 32M
sort_buffer_size = 12M
read_buffer_size = 12M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 6M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
query_cache_size = 512M
query_cache_type = 1
join_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_connections = 2048
max_heap_table_size = 64M
wait_timeout = 3000

skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve

# InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 24G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 256M
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

DB2 has CPU with 16 threads and 64GB of RAM. The my.cnf configuration is as follows:

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log

symbolic-links=0

# Fine Tuning
thread_stack = 512K
key_buffer = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
thread_concurrency = 8
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type = 1
join_buffer_size = 8M
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_connections = 800
max_heap_table_size = 32M
wait_timeout = 5000

skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve

# InnoDB
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 40M
innodb_file_per_table=1

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

Anyone who knows what may be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: And the network link between DB1 and DB2?

Comment: Additional information request for DB1 and DB2 server for comparison. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis between DB1 and DB2 for CAUSE(s) of your timing differences.

Comment: @jsgarcia      Any chance of you posting requested information for analysis?

Answer (score 0):

A large `query_cache_size` can *hurt* performance.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is quite different between the servers.  How big is the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for DB1 to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=128K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
query_cache_size=64M
tmp_table_size=164M
max_heap_table_size=164M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100
innodb_log_file_size=256M
```

Let us know how you are doing after implementation on DB1, please.